# How deep do you go when performing a true "deep copy"?

Tags: pointers, object, deep-copy, cloning

Say you have an object with a pointer a that points to an object 1.

I understand that if object 1 is not a pointer, you make a clone of object 1 say object 2, and create a new pointer b to to object 2. Pointer b is then what's placed in the copy of the original object.

This is how deep copy works.

What if object 1 is a pointer that points to another object? Do you make a copy of both of these objects for a deep copy? Or just the "first level" object?

Essentially, how deep do you go when performing a true deep copy? I assume you go as deep as possible and copy everything, but I want to double check.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, a true "deep copy" will copy everything - recursively making deep copies of any and all nested objects.

However, this may not always be practical or desirable. It depends on your particular situation:

- If your data structure contains cycles or refers to the same object multiple times, you will need to track and handle this somehow or the copying will continue on to infinity
- Some objects may be "safe" to refer to by pointer without creating a copy (e.g. if they are immutable), so copying them may be wasteful. You may want to specifically exempt these from the copying process

Comment: Thank you for confirming what I thought. You bring up interesting cases to consider which I had not though of before. Thank you for pointing them out.